# Are the power operations in the representation ring visible in the centre of the group ring?

Tags: finite-groups, solution-verification, representation-theory

On the representation ring of a finite group $G$ we have power operations $\Psi^p:R[G]\rightarrow R[G]$ given on characters by $\Psi^p(\chi)(g)=\chi(g^p)$. We can easily see that these are ring endomorphisms, after checking that the image of a character lands in $R[G]$.

We may view irreducible characters as the primitive idempotents of the centre of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ via the mapping: $$ \chi_V\mapsto \sum_{g\in G}\frac{\overline{\chi_V(g)}\dim V.e_g}{|G|}$$

Then for $p$ coprime to the order of $G$, we can define a map $\Psi^p:Z(\mathbb{Z}[G])\rightarrow Z(\mathbb{Z}[G])$ given by mapping a conjugacy class sum $C_g$ to $C_{g^{1/p}}$, the conjugacy class of the unique $p$th root of any element of $C_g$. We can also see that over $\mathbb{C}$, this map permutes our primitive idempotents.

So if this reasoning is all legitimate, then the conjugacy class permuting $\Psi^p$ become ring endomorphisms over $\mathbb{C}$, so must have been endomorphisms originally of the centre of the group ring. This leads to my question, is it true that these linear maps are actually ring endomorphisms of the centre of the group ring?

This seems quite hard to believe, for instance, in an odd order group, why should square roots of the product of elements be strongly related the the square roots of the products, without abelian hypotheses?

Is there either an issue with this reasoning (or an easy counterexample), or a simple proof of the underlying group theory at play?